# How to get list index values from an unlist variable?

Tags: flutter

```
var _first=<double> [108,105,90.833,87.7,88.6];
 var _answers=<double>[];
 for (var i=0; i<_first.length;i++){
   _answers.add(_first[i]);
   double _cosa = Angle.degrees(_first[i]).cos;
print (_cosa);
**double a=_cosa[0];
double b=_cosa[1];
double c=_cosa[2];
double d=_cosa[3];
double e=_cosa[4];**
```

There are 5 values in the print of the `_cosa` variable, and I want to get
all 5 values in 5 different variables like I typed the code, but this throws an error.
So, can anyone tell me the correct code?

Comment: `_cosa` is only a single value, not a `List`.  Also, currently `_answers` is just a copy of `_first`.  Perhaps you intend to do: `for (var degrees in _first) { _answers.add(Angle.degrees(degrees).cos); } var a = answers[0]; var b = answers[1]; ...`?

Answer (score 0):

I think creating variables like you want is not very good idea. However,I recommend you to use Map to get any data(or value) within Map by 'key'. Here is example:

```
 List<double> _first=<double> [108,105,90.833,87.7,88.6];
  Map<String,double> _answers={};
 for (var i=0; i<_first.length;i++){
   _answers['b${i}']=_first[i]; // you can  change 'b${i}' key as you want
 }
  
   double _cosa = Angle.degrees(_answers['a1']).cos;
   print (_cosa);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you seem to be mistaken on what `_cosa` is. `_cosa` is not a list of values, it is a value in itself, meaning it has only one value inside itself.

You loop through each value in `_first` and do the following:

```
double _cosa = Angle.degrees(_first[i]).cos;
```

There are 2 things wrong with this piece of code:

1. You assign to `_cosa` directly:

That is to say, every time you loop you are saying `_cosa` is equal to the current angle's sin wave. Meaning that by the time the loop is done, the `_cosa` variable will only contain the **last** item's sin wave, not a list of all. You should declare the `_cosa` variable as a list just like you did for the previous items:

```
var _cosa = <double>[0,0,0,0,0];
_cosa[i] = Angle.degrees(_first[i]).cos;
```

A smarter way to do this, so that you don't have to declare `_cosa` with a bunch of ugly ceroes, is to use the `add` method:

```
var _cosa = <double>[];
_cosa.add(Angle.degrees(_first[i]).cos);
```

This solves the first issue, but it still won't work, because:

2. You declare cosa inside the loop itself:

if you run the code above in the loop itself, every time the loop runs (5 times) this line also runs:

```
var _cosa = <double>[];
```

which will do two things, because you declare the variable inside the loop, you will get an error for using it outside the loop. Remember that every variable declared inside a loop (or inside `{}` in general) gets destroyed as soon as you leave said loop.

The second thing it does is assign make `_cosa` be empty every loop, effectively deleting all of the data you store in it.

To fix this, move the declaration of `_cosa` to before the loop:

```
var _first=<double> [108,105,90.833,87.7,88.6];
 var _answers=<double>[];
 var _cosa = <double>[];
 for (var i=0; i<_first.length;i++) {
   _answers.add(_first[i]);
   _cosa.add(Angle.degrees(_first[i]).cos);
}

print (_cosa);
double a=_cosa[0];
double b=_cosa[1];
double c=_cosa[2];
double d=_cosa[3];
double e=_cosa[4];
```